# How to put one paragraph below other with float right?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put all my elements to the right side of the page using `float: right` and the only issue that I'm having is the position of the last paragraph, instead of just being below of top paragraph it goes below and moves to the left.

Here you have a JSFiddle to a better understand of my issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/5782o1hg/1/

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right"/>
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 0 15px"/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin: 2px 0 0 0">DreamGlass</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right">Ola</p>
</div>
```

I just want to put the "World" paragraph bellow of the top one without moving to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CSS grid solution:

```css
.grid {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.items {
  justify-self: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>CSS grid</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="items item-1">DreamGlass</div>
    <div class="items item-2">kiwi.svg</div>
    <div class="items item-3">Ola</div>
    <div class="items item-4">kiwi.svg</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## text-align right solution

```css
.p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>text-align right solution</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="p">paragraph-1</p>
    <p class="p">paragraph-2</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why are you not suggesting a grid-based solution?

Comment: I hope, it helps.

Comment: Im using css-grid in others situations and to be honest I prefer the awnser that you had before.

Comment: @LOLJovem Yeah, but i think, that you have much more possibilities with css-grid, because it is a strict layout. I had a lot of issues, when i tried, to position stuff without it so it is a good thing over all to have it in mind. That's why i suggested it...

Comment: Will take your suggestion in mind and work more with css-grid. Just saying that I preferred the other one cause is way simple and fast to do.

Comment: @LOLJovem Just added an update with the first solution as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, isn't for me but for all the people who will see this post.

Comment: @LOLJovem Yeah, thanks for reminding me of that. I kinda forgot about that :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is put 'World' into the 'Hello' paragraph adding a line break between both words:

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right"/>
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 0 15px"/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin: 2px 0 0 0">Hello<br /> World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your awnser it's correct, I tried before that, but one thing, that I forget to say, when the first word is bigger than the second one the second one stay with some space in the right. My bad for forgetting to saying that. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you need to align the text to the right side, just add the text-align: right; property to the paragraph styles.

Comment: Yes one guy gave me that solution and I think its the better one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right"/>
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 0 15px"/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin: 2px 0 0 0;width:100%;text-align:right;">Hello</p>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right;width:100%;text-align:right;">World</p>
</div>
```

thats all...

Comment: If you take off the float: right in the paragraphs you catch the result that I want. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can create "wrapper" `<div>` and put in your paragraphes

[Result on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eupmnj9f/1/)

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right" />
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 0 15px" />
  <div style="float:right;">
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin: 2px 0 0 0">DreamGlass</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right">Ola</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution but if I dont want that `<br/>` the result will be the same but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a negative margin-right to the world paragraph.

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right"/>
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 0 15px"/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin: 2px 0 0 0">Hello</p>
    <br/>
    <p style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin-right: -50px">World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Its a solution but not seems to be the most reliable but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the two paragraphs into a `div` with `style = "float: right;"`

Replace `<p>` tags with `<span>` and adjust styles in both as needed

```html
<div style="height: 100%">
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right"/>
    <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="float: right; margin: 0 0 0 15px"/>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <span style="font-size: 20px; margin: 2px 0 0 0">DreamGlass</span>
        <br />
        <span style="font-size: 20px; float: right; margin: 2px 4px 0 0">Ola</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct but one thing, that I forget to say, as you can see the word "Ola" have some space in the right It was my bad but thank you anyway.

Comment: Your reply made me play with the code again _ Code updated but using `<span>` instead of `<p>`  _ Thanks for the upvote & Welcome to Stack Overflow : )

Comment: Thank you for you patience and for looking the best awnser that you can give! Appreciate it a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use flexbox instead of float

```html
<div style="height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-end;">
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50"/>
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50"/>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; margin: 2px 0 0 0">DreamGlass</p>
  <p style="font-size: 20px;">Ola</p>
</div>
```

Still not want to use flexbox then just making some changes on your code will do this for you. Remove float and add style "text-align: right;" to the parent. Also add a line break after image

```html
<div style="height: 100%; text-align: right;">
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" /><br>
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" width="50" height="50" style="margin: 0 0 0 15px"/><br>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; margin: 2px 0 0 0">DreamGlass</p>
  <p style="font-size: 20px;">Ola</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want all bellow all, just the second paragraph bellow the first one. But thank you!